# Is it possible to get report in sonarqube on how issues are handled?

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to get report in sonarqube on how issues are handled? I.e. Comment, Assign, Confirm, Change Severity, Resolve, Won't Fix, and False Positive? We would like to get insight on how teams are using sonarqube.

Answer (score 1):

To some degree this is immediately available in your issues page search facets. Go to the project and then to its issues page. Expand the Status and Resolution facets, which are collapsed by default, and you'll see issue counts of Fixed, False Positive, Won't Fix, and Confirmed issues. You can narrow the set and see sub-breakdowns by clicking on any facet value; the rest of the values will adjust accordingly.

What you *won't* see here are the number of issues with

- comments
- adjusted severities

In terms of issue assignment, you also won't get much help here because most issues are auto-assigned at creation, and the facets won't tell you how many have been re-assigned.